# How to define an interval list in (Android) Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, set, intervals

I have a list of intervals, that each have a corresponding string value, something like

```
1-10 -> "String Value 1"
11-50 -> "String Value 2"
51-63 -> "String Value 3"
64-1000 -> "String Value 4"
1001-100000 -> "String Value 5"
etc.
```

And then I have to get the string value for any number in an optimal way:

getStringValue(40) -> "String Value 2"

I want to use a structure (array/collection/list), and not multiple if/else instuctions.

Thank you

Comment: How many ranges are there? Is it worth it to design a solution just to save yourself time coding the if/else or switch statements?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja About 10 ranges. How could it be implemented with switch statements, as case statements don't support ranges?

Comment: In Java, you can't reasonably use switch statements for this type of problem. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing a page from Ruby, you could do a data structure which maps a pair of values to a result, as follows:

```
Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> mapping = new HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String>();
mapping.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1, 10), "String Value 1");
mapping.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(11, 50), "String Value 2");
// ...
mapping.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(1001, 100000), "String Value 5");
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
public String getStringValue(int x) {
    for (Pair<Integer, Integer> range : mapping.keySet()) {
        if (x >= range.first && x <= range.second) {
            return mapping.get(range);
        }
    }
    return null;  // or throw exception, or whatever
}
```

<strike>Keep in mind that your ranges overlap, as you've defined them in the problem, so you'll need to handle edges appropriately. My implementation assumes that your ranges are lower-bound-inclusive and upper-bound-exclusive; with the given values, `1` will resolve to `"String Value 1"`, but `10` will resolve to `"String Value 2"`.</strike>

**EDIT** I've modified the ranges to match the edits to the original question. All ranges, and the logic above, are upper- and lower-bound inclusive.

**P. S.** Since you're on Android, you have access to a perfectly-suitable Pair implementation at `android.util.Pair`.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the question to reflect the fact that ranges do not overlap. I'll try this solution, it looks quite elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Considering your edits, you'd need to change the if-condition to `if (x >= range.first && x <= range.second)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Map<Integer, String>` that maps numbers into their correct category. The entries of the map are going to look like:

```
1 => String Value 1
2 => String Value 1
...
10 => String Value 2
...
60 => String Value 3
etc...
```

You can build it by iterating over the intervals and putting the correct values into the map, for example:

```
for (int n : interval) {
    map.put(n, intervalStringValue);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the example in my question: the intervals can grow very large,  would creating a map of 100000 elements be optimal?

Comment: 100000 is probably fine, if you grow more it could be a problem. Otherwise you could create something like an Interval class (storing start and end of interval) with a method `include(int value)`; then you have to search the correct interval among the keys and access is no more O(1) but O(log n) if you implement a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

I like Coding Monk's solution, which is realistically probably fine up to a range in the hundreds of thousands. If you want a more flexible solution you can keep a sorted list of intervals objects. Then you can perform binary search on that list to find the corresponding interval, and then use a map to find your string corresponding to that interval. I doubt the added complexity is needed in this case though.